# Firefox Addon : Event on a specific command line

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying that when the user enters a command in the Web console, I get this command in the script of my addon before to be executed?

For example, when the user enters the command line "screenshot --fullpage" this command to be sent to a function of the script of my addon before being executed.

I did some research but I only found an event on the opening of the web console.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications#Developer_tools

Comment: So you want to add keywords to the command line?

Comment: No, I want that when a command is entered, a function is executed prior to the execution of this command with parameter input command.

Comment: Oh that's a cool idea, and easily doable, you'll have to search http://dxr.mozilla.org/

Comment: A person on the Mozilla forum told me the same thing, but I do not understand all the code and I have the impression that some components are not accessible.

Comment: This is a great place to read - https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/devtools/shared/gcli/source/docs

Comment: I added a reply here - https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/t/firefox-addon-event-on-a-specific-command-line/6028/8 - hopefully someone can help us out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution posted here - https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/t/firefox-addon-event-on-a-specific-command-line/6028/10?u=noitidart

Alrighty here we go, this works:

```
var { require } = Cu.import("resource://devtools/shared/Loader.jsm", {});

var tmp = {};
Cu.import("resource://devtools/client/shared/DeveloperToolbar.jsm", tmp);

var gcliInit = require('devtools/shared/gcli/commands/index');
var { TargetFactory } = require("devtools/client/framework/target");

var a = new tmp.DeveloperToolbar(window, document.getElementById("developer-toolbar"));

var sysTarget= TargetFactory.forTab(a._chromeWindow.gBrowser.selectedTab);

gcliInit.getSystem(sysTarget).then(
    system => {
        console.log('system:',system);
        system.addItems([{
            name: 'greet',
            description: 'Show a greeting',
            params: [{
                name: 'name',
                type: 'string',
                description: 'The name to greet'
            }],
            returnType: 'string',
            exec: function(args, context) {
                return 'Hello, ' + args.name;
            }
        }]);
    },
    y => console.error('y:',y)
);
```

Note, the path changes in Firefox 45. So this code is for Fx45+ prior to this you would use `resource://gre/modules/devtools/Loader.jsm` instead of `resource://devtools/shared/Loader.jsm`.

TargetFactor was the key component I was missing, it's important, it's got these methods:

```
 Object { forTab: function (), forRemoteTab: function (), forWorker: function (), isKnownTab: function () }
```